# Angular Way: Repeat elements grouped

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there any Angular way of grouping some elements together when listing them?
For example, if we have some data like this:

```
[{Name: "Ted", Age: 21}, {Name: "Ady", Age: 23}, {Name: "Ella", Age: 18}, {Name: "Geo", Age: 17}]
```

And we expect the output below:

```
<ul>
    <li>Ted</li>
    <li>Ady</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Ella</li>
    <li>Geo</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the criteria for your grouping?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention. Grouped by a random number.

Comment: I think what you require is a `ng-repeat` inside your `ng-repeat` cue Exibit.

Comment: Yes. That could be a way but this means that the data should be already grouped, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom filter, then have two `ng-repeat`s;

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in myArray | myFilter:arg" ng-bind="item.Name">
</ul>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in myArray | myFilter:arg" ng-bind="item.Name">
</ul>
```

You could set `arg` equal to whatever you're grouping by.

You can see how to make [custom filters here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09).

Comment: won't this return `<ul><li></ul><ul><li></ul>...` when he wants  `<ul><li><li></ul><ul><li><li></ul>...`?

Comment: @Joe yeah it would, my bad, bed time for me ;P (updated)